# Calculate count of particular day fall in between two dates

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I need an Amazon Redshift SQL query to calculate the number of a particular day fall in between two dates.
Date Format - YYYY-MM-DD
For example - Start date = 2019-06-14, End Date = 2019-10-09, Day - 2nd of every month

Now, I want to calculate the count of 2nd-day fall in between 2019-06-14 and 2019-10-09

So, the actual result for the above example should be 4. Since 4 times the 2nd-day will fall in between 2019-06-14 and 2019-10-09.

I tried the DATE_DIFF function and months_between function of redshift. But failed to build the logic. Since not able to understand what math or equation should be.

Comment: you need date_diff in months + 1 month if the start date is < 2nd - 1 month if the end date is < 2nd - something like that - experiment.

Answer (score 0):

for me it seems as if you wanted to select from a calendar table. That's how you can solve your problem. You'll notice that the query looks a little hacky because Redshift does not support any functions to generate sequences, which leaves you with creating sequence tables yourself (see `seq_10` and `seq_1000`). Once you have a sequence, you can easily create a `calendar` with all the information you need (eg. `day_of_month`).

That's the query answering your question:

```
WITH seq_10 as (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
), seq_1000 as (
    select
           row_number() over () - 1 as n
    from
         seq_10 a cross join
         seq_10 b cross join
         seq_10 c
), calendar as (
    select '2018-01-01'::date + n as date,
    extract(day from date) as day_of_month,
    extract(dow from date) as day_of_week
    from seq_1000
)
select count(*) from calendar
where day_of_month = 2
and date between '2019-06-14' and '2019-10-09'
```